# SQL select query, multiple tables

Tags: sql

i was wondering if you could help me construct a query here

What i have is 2 Tables:

`Posts` and `Images`

Every entery in `Images` has a row called "`post_assoc`", which is set to the ID of a entery in the "`Posts`" Table, i want to select all `Posts` enteries that do not have a image entery pointing to them, is this possible without any server side script sorting ?

Feel free to ask if you need elaboration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run this query in your management software. And the result will be all posts without images.

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE ID NOT IN ( SELECT post_assoc FROM Images )
```

Comment: Ty very much, i did not realise the query could be that simple

Comment: @JohnDOe - That's the power of SQL, when you know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Posts P left join Images I on (I.post_assoc = P.id) where I.post_assoc is null
```